# Uncaught ReferenceError: tankperson is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am running an AJAX request when the page loads, however I am seeing this error. I have included all the necessary libraries.

tankperson is the result from `$_GET['name']`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tankperson is not defined
>   at select (user.php?name=tankperson:67)
>   at user.php?name=tankperson:59

```
<div id="here">

<script>

// LINE 59 
window.onload = select();

function select() {
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "page.php",
       //LINE 67 
       data: "user=" + <?php echo ($_GET['name']); ?>, 
       success: function(data) {
           $("#here").html(data());
       }
   })
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the PHP statement in quotes:

```
function select() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.php",
        //LINE 67
        data: "user=" + "<?php echo ($_GET['name']); ?>",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#here").html(data());
        }
    })
}
```

Without the quotes you're referring to a constant/variable with a name equal to the value of your PHP variable (tankperson) which is not defined, hence the `ReferenceError`

If you take a look at the generated HTML source code it's easier to spot the issue:

```
function select() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.php",
        //LINE 67
        data: "user=" + tankperson,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#here").html(data());
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please could you accept the answer if it solves your issue?